# How to mock named const exports with Jest on a per-case basis?

Tags: jestjs

I have a module `constants.js` that returns multiple constant objects:

```
export const SERVER = {
  HOST: 'localhost',
  PORT: 8000,
};

export const PATHS = {
  LOGIN: '/login',
  LOGOUT: '/logout',
};
```

I'm using [PactJS](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js), and in order for me to do parallel tests with Jest, I have to use a different port on every `it()` test case. So I want to change the value of `SERVER.PORT` on `beforeEach()`.

This is what I have so far, which is not working:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  port = getRandomPort();

  jest.doMock('./constants', () => ({
    SERVER: {
      PORT: port,
    },
  })
});
```

The module under test, when loading `constants.js` loads it with the actual values instead of the mocked ones. So this is not working.

I have also tried using `jest.mock()` instead of `jest.doMock()` and return a mock function, so I can change the `.mockReturnValue()` but since `constants.js` doesn't export a function, but an object, doing this makes no sense, so it doesn't work either.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a mock file for the constants `__mocks__/constants.js` and requiring the actual file inside:

```
// __mocks__/constants.js
const actualConstants = require.requireActual('../constants');

export default {
  ...actualConstants,

  aSingleConstant: 'mocked value',
};
```